# Meaning of different lambda functions and characters

Tags: haskell, lambda, syntax

At the moment I am learning Haskell, but I am struggling with the syntax of a few example. What do they exactly mean?

**First**: What is the difference between these two lambdas (`-> \y` and `y`)?

```
lambda1 = \x -> \y -> x + y
lambda2 = \x y -> x + y
```

**Second**: What does this mean? Is this a lambda that act as a "pseudo" list generator that generates a list with 3 elements. How can I create such a list?

```
lambda3 = [\x -> x+1, \x -> 2*x, \x -> x^2]
```

**Third**: What does the `\_` exactly mean?

```
lambda4 = \_ -> (\x -> x+1, \() -> 'a')
```

Answer (score 10):

`lambda2` is syntactic sugar for `lambda1`. All of these are equivalent:

```
f = \x -> \y -> x + y
f = \x y -> x + y
f x = \y -> x + y
f x y = x + y
f x y = (+) x y
f x = (+) x
f = (+)
```

`lambda3` is a list of unary functions on numbers. Each function has the type `(Num a) => a -> a`, so the list has type `(Num a) => [a -> a]`. You could produce a list of values from this with `map` or a list comprehension:

```
fs = [\x -> x+1, \x -> 2*x, \x -> x^2]

map (\f -> f 3) fs
map ($ 3) fs
[f 3 | f <- fs]
==
[4, 6, 9]
```

`lambda4` uses pattern-matching syntax. For example, if you have a data type:

```
data Foo = Foo Int String
```

Then you can write a lambda that pattern-matches on it:

```
f = \ (Foo n s) -> concat (replicate n s)

f (Foo 3 "bar") == "barbarbar"
```

(But unlike `case`, there is no way to provide alternative patterns if `Foo` has multiple constructors.)

The `_` pattern just says “accept a value and ignore it”, so `lambda4` is a function that accepts an argument, ignores it, and returns a pair (2-tuple) of unary functions, the first of type `(Num a) => a -> a` and the second of type `() -> Char`, so its type is `Num a => r -> (a -> a, () -> Char)`.

```
lambda4 = \_ -> (\x -> x+1, \() -> 'a')
lambda4 = \ignored -> (\x -> x+1, \() -> 'a')

(inc, getA) = lambda4 ()
inc 3 == 4
getA () == 'a'
```

Functions that ignore their arguments can be constructed with the `const` function, and operator sections (`(+ 1)`) are typically preferred over lambdas (`\x -> x + 1`), so you can also write the above as:

```
lambda4 = const ((+ 1), const 'a')
```

Answer (score 3):

> First: What is the difference between these two lambdas (-> \y and y)?

There is no difference. Both produce the same output for the same input, and since they're pure functions, you can be sure that they produce no external effects that you wouldn't see.

The difference lies in that the first lambda uses syntactic sugar for [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying).
`\x y -> x + y` is equal to `\x -> \y -> x + y`. Now, don't you think it looks a lot like type signatures, such as `foo :: Int -> Int -> Int` ? ;)
It means that the function `foo` takes 2 `Int` and produces an `Int`.

Since I don't have a very precise answer for the 2nd…

> Third: What does the `\_` exactly mean?

It's a lambda function (`\`) to which is associated the `_` variable. `_` is used as a placeholder to say “I don't care about the content of this variable, I'm even going to give it a proper name”.

Comment: While your answer is essentially correct, "currying" is not quite the right term for the difference between the two definitions in the first question (currying involves going from `(a, b) -> c` to `a -> b -> c`, and there are no pairs involved here). I'm not even sure if there is a specific term for that, other than "syntactic sugar".

Comment: [Section 3.3 of the Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-260003.3), which specifies what we are talking about, is titled "Curried Applications and Lambda Abstractions". Taking my cue from that, I think it would be fine to say, at the beginning of the second paragraph here, that "The difference lies in that the first lambda uses syntax sugar for currying".

Answer (score 3):

On your second question, `lambda3` is just a bad variable name. this is a list of functions of type `Num a => a -> a`. You can verify that by typing the following in ghci:

```
:t [\x -> x+1, \x -> 2*x, \x -> x^2]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `-> y`. The correct way to read this is

```
(\ x -> (\ y -> (x + y)))
```

As it happens, Haskell has "curried functions", which means that

```
\ x y -> (x + y)
```

just happens to be equivalent to the above.

---

`lambda3` is a list which contains three elements. Each of those elements happens to be a function. Functions are data in Haskell; you can pass them as arguments, return them as results, stuff them into lists, etc.

```
lambda3 = [ (\x -> x+1) , (\x -> 2*x) , (\x -> x^2) ]
```

---

```
lambda4 = \_ -> (\x -> x+1, \() -> 'a')
```

The "`_`" character basically means "I don't care what this is; ignore it". You can use it anywhere you can use a pattern. For example,

```
foobar x _ z = x + y
```

is a 3-argument function that completely ignores argument #2. Read about pattern matching and this should become clear. (I.e., it's not to do with lambdas, it's to do with patterns.)